# Get the closest (in past) time based on a string

Tags: php

I want to create a function that can find the closest time, based in a string of second.

The system will receive an int number that equivalent of second of that time.
PHP must find the closest (in past) date.

Example:

```
//supose that an anterior script created it at "14-08-25 10:32:30"
//and now it's "14-08-25 10:33:12"
$seconds = 30; // the variable passed from an anterior script
$time_received= date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // this is the time that I'll receive this 
//so, from these 2 variables above, i must find "14-08-25 10:32:30"
```

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

I have just these variables:
The time right now, that is "14-08-25 10:33:12"
and the $seconds variable.

With these 2, I want to get "14-08-25 10:32:30"

Comment: Find it from where? Out of database, text file, array?

Comment: Nothing of this. I already have these values in my script.
I just receive $seconds

Comment: I'm not sure at all how one is to arrive at "14-08-25 10:32:30" given "14-08-25 10:33:32" and "30". You'll have to clarify a bit here.

Comment: sorry, I write the wrong time. I've corrected and tried to explain more.

Comment: So... *if secondsOfTime < `$seconds` then minuteOfTime - 1; secondsOfTime = `$seconds`*?!

Comment: Yes, right! Now I need to know how generate the old date (14-08-25 10:32:30)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't completely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but I'm making a guess by using [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime):

```
<?php
$seconds = 30;
$time = strtotime("-" . $seconds . " seconds");
echo date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", $time );
?>
```

Comment: Almost. But I don't need remove these 30 seconds. I need to find the full time, like "14-08-25 10:32:30" (The $seconds variable must correspond, not decrease)

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

Found.
I'm using this script:

```
$seconds = 30; 
$new_date = new DateTime(date()); //the only two variables that i have

if($new_date->format('s')<$seconds){
    $new_date->setTime($new_date->format('H'),$new_date->format('i')-1,$seconds);
    $old_date = $new_date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
}else{
    $new_date->setTime($new_date->format('H'),$new_date->format('i'),$seconds);
    $old_date = $new_date->format('Y/m/d H:i:s');
}
```